# Images don't display after URL Rewrite - php

Tags: php, image, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I rewrote the URLs on information.php to have pretty URLs as below and it is working fine:

Old URL: http://www.example.com/workfolder/information.php?business_name=any-business-name
New URL: http://www.example.com/workfolder/business/any-business-name

I used the following code in .htaccess file to do that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /workfolder/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /information\?business_name=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ business/%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^business/([^/]+)/?$ information?business_name=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

However once I did the above URL rewrite, the dynamic images calling in information.php are not displaying in new URLs (Ex: the images are not displaying in example.com/workfolder/business/any-business-name)

The images are in the images folder and when I try to view the image in the example.com/workfolder/business/any-business-name page, it goes to the following page:

example.com/workfolder/**business**/images/image1.jpg

This page doesn't have the image since the path is not correct because /**business**/ is not an existing folder.

I have used the following code in the .htaccess file, but it still doesn't display the images.

```
# fix js/images/css
RewriteRule ^.+?/((img|css|js)/.+)$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

I have also tried the following code in the in the   tags, but it still doesn't display the images.

```
<base href="/">
```

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: use absolute path in your `img` tag. `<img src="http://domain.com/img/1.jpg" />`

Comment: I used absolute path and it works. Thank you.